# Germany Schengen visa type D to blue card - travel restrictions on first arrival

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas

I am Indian, presently resident in Egypt.

I received a German Type D Schengen multiple-entry visa with 7 month's validity, when I applied for the Blue Card work visa.

I am planning to visit Germany for few days and return to Egypt for a month before permanently moving to Germany.

I was informed that, once I arrive in Germany on this visa type, travel is restricted within the Schengen countries or back and forth to your home country. So, in my case, I can't go back to Egypt.

Are these restrictions correct? Will there be issues with the border control officer when I arrive at German Immigration?

Comment: Does "home country" mean country of citizenship or country of residence?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan "So, in my case, I can't go back to Egypt."

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, home country or country of citizenship which is india.

Comment: @pnuts, we have a 3rd party consultant in germany taking care of this visa stuff, this is their info....